# The Activity that use the Theme.Dialog when i exit app but the dialog still show

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog, android-theme

1.In my service when i accept a alram info i show a Activity Dialog.

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.teco.powercloud.common.EmergencyRemindActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/DialogActivityStyle" >
    </activity>


    Intent mActivityIntent = new Intent();
    mActivityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    mActivityIntent.putExtra(Constant.KEY_WARNING_INFO,warningEventInfo);
    if(warningEventInfo.alarm_status == Constant.WARNING_TYPE_TEMP_JUMP_WARNING){
        mActivityIntent.setClass(mContext, EmergencyRemindActivity.class);
    }else{
        mActivityIntent.setClass(mContext, AlarmRemindActivity.class);
    }
    mContext.startActivity(mActivityIntent);
```

2.when i exit app i use the below code.

```
            stopService(new Intent(MainPageActivity.this,AlarmDetectService.class));
            TecomPPManager.getInstance().resetStatusUnLock();
            TecomPPManager.getInstance().shutDownThreadPool();
            BitmapUtil.clearCache();//清空bitmap缓存
            MainPageActivity.this.finish();
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                ActivityManager activityMgr = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                activityMgr.killBackgroundProcesses(getPackageName());
```

3.But the problem is that：sometimes,the activity dialog isn't showing,
then i exit app but i occurs that the Activity Dialog is showing。why？

Comment: make sure where you are displaying the dialog box and after performing some action on dialog box call dialog.dismiss() method

Comment: @Tara it is a activity that use the style Theme.Dialog

Comment: You need to post your manifest. Also explain where this "shutdown code" is being called. Also, why are you killing all the processes?